# How to send the task variable in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a menu item in joomla (virtuemart) with url

```
index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=manufacturer
```

Now, in view.html.php of manufacturer view I added a function called jump as

```
function jump(){echo "hello";}
```

I added task=jump in the url so that it becomes

```
index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=manufacturer&task=jump
```

But even now the default display function executes and not the jump function. Why? Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task in this url   `index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=manufacturer&task=jump` will execute the `jump` function of default controller.So if there is any function `jump` in the  `controller.php` will execute not the jump function of view.If you want to execute jump of any other controller use this structure `task=controllername.taskname`

Read More - http://docs.joomla.org/JController_and_its_subclass_usage_overview
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/joomla-dev-general/ZkNhbX2x1Es
http://docs.joomla.org/How_Joomla_pieces_work_together

Hope this is clear.

Comment: thanks but I want to execute a different function of my view other than display... is it not possible by changing the url? then how can i achieve it? thanks..

Comment: @user1877095: I have added some references that will help you to understand mvc . And will also help to solve your problem.Display is default function you can call different function in your controller.